# Customised Data Validation System for Data Count and Quality check in sql server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to design and Develop a Data Validation system

Scenario:-

Data Quality Validation between Source, RAW, Staging,validation and Target.
Data Flows from Source to RAW, Staging,validation and Target  using ETL (SSIS) tool.
Each stage perform predefined task like cleasing and Aggregation.... etc

I want to design a Data Validation system which gives me clear picture for my data how it looks after each stage.

There should be 1 table for each source, as schema for each source is different.

- What should be my design approach for building solution
- which can tell data story, correctness and completeness between Source, RAW, Staging,validation and Target.

Moreover how to accommodate ETL Script which is altering data between each stage., so if data got change from 1 point to another
I can tell it happen due to ETL Script....**Seems really challenging**.....

May Anyone already develop this kind of system, please help me with your expertise knowledge. All points I should focused on while doing modelling.